# Powershell Where-Object replace is not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace this object that has a string assigned for sorting as "zNo Creator Found" with "No Creator Found". I've tried several different ways but the string never gets replaced:

`Where-Object { ($_.Creator -replace 'zNo Creator Found','No Creator Found') }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For modifying an object, you want to use `ForEach-Object`, which has a handy alias as `%`. While `Where-Object` would technically work in this case, it's confusing to code readers as `Where-Object` is intended for filtering a collection based on a condition. If you want to perform some action on each object of a collection, use `ForEach-Object`.
2. .NET strings are immutable so you can't modify the string in place. You have to reassign the string.

`ForEach-Object { $_.Creator = ($_.Creator -replace 'zNo Creator Found','No Creator Found') }`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a linux guy and have been using PowerShell for less than a month :). I ended up enclosing it in:
``` new-object psobject -Property @{```